# Is there a way of rendering routes inside component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm creating a management page for my website and I'd like to create routes inside the control panel for when I click in an option it redirects me to its content without having to reload the whole template (header, menu, etc).
I already have I `routes.js` file that I use to redirect from the outer pages (login page and others) and I'd like to route my sub sections inside a "content component" but I can't realize how to do that.

I've tried something like this:

```
<Router>
  <div className="panel">
    <Header />
    <Menu />
    <Content />
  </div>
</Router>
```

inside my content I created this structure:

```
<div className="content">
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/panel" component={Products} />
    <Route
      path="/panel/dashboards"
      component={Dashboards}
    />
  </Switch>
</div>
```

But it keeps reloading the whole page.

Comment: Are you talking about creating internal routers between different components connected to the same component ?

Comment: It might be as simple as putting the `<Router>` only around the parts that actually change based on the route, as opposed to all main components.

Comment: @CanUver Yes, I have a component called content, and I need to route different components into it.

Comment: @ChrisG I've already tried it, but it keeps redirecting the whole page :(

Comment: Okay. Why do you want to do this ? I mean, I wonder what you expect this to bring to you. https://stackoverflow.com/q/49001001/12348877 this could be similar to what you're looking for.

Comment: @CanUver The thing is: I have two different sections in my website. the unauthorized zone, where an user can log in, and the authorized zone, where I have the control panel. Only the control panel has a menu template with sub-pages (dashboards, infos, etc). So I need to handle 2 routers, the first one is a general router that handles both zones, and the other one needs to handle the sub-routes  inside the control panel.