# How to best handle the state of one component used by two urls (1 sub url) in React / Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following urls that route to the same component. I want to use the same component for two scenarios, either a new blank version or an existing one which is then pre-populated via API fetch using the url parameter.

Once I change my url from e.g.
`http://localhost:3000/dashboard/planner/1` to
`http://localhost:3000/dashboard/planner/`
the component remains its state and doesn't reset. The console.log in `useEffect` also doesn't re-trigger.

My approach was to define a boolean logic `is_existing_offer` in the `useEffect` hook.

So I guess I need to somehow re-render the component once changing the url as I can't call `useEffect` again or use another method to update its state when jumping to `http://localhost:3000/dashboard/planner/`?

[This didn't help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001001/using-same-component-for-different-route-path-in-react-router-v4)

```
<Routes>
    <Route key="planner_id" path="planner/:id" element={<PlannerWrapper is_existing_offer={true}/>}/>
    <Route key="planner_default" path="planner/" element={<PlannerWrapper is_existing_offer={false}/>}/>
</Routes>
```

```
// PlannerWrapper

const PlannerWrapper = (props) => {

    // Get the offer's uuid from route to make API call and fetch the offer
    const params = useParams()

..

    // Fetch the associated offer via API and pre-populate components, only runs once at mount
    // Only runs if it is not the blank planner instance
    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.is_existing_offer) {
            fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/offer/${params.id}`, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(result => {
                console.log('Success:', result);
                setValues(result)
            })
        }
        else {
            setValues(initial_state)
        }
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because the route changes doesn't mean the component is remounted.

### Add `params.id` to the dependency array

Adding `params.id` to the `useEffect` hook will trigger its callback when the route changes and the `id` value changes. Don't rely on the `is_existing_offer` as this doesn't trigger the `useEffect` and the `id` alone is the *actual* dependency since it is referenced.

```
const PlannerWrapper = (props) => {
  // Get the offer's uuid from route to make API call and fetch the offer
  const { id } = useParams()

  ...

  // Fetch the associated offer via API and pre-populate components, runs when `id` updates
  // Only runs if `id` is truthy, i.e. defined
  useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/offer/${id}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
          console.log('Success:', result);
          setValues(result);
        })
    } else {
      setValues(initial_state);
    }
  }, [id]); // <-- id is referenced so it's a dependency

  ...
```

### Add a React key *to the routed component*

Add the React key to the component you want it to actually differentiate, in this case it's the routed component, not the route. You can also simplify boolean props to just the prop name. If a `is_existing_offer` prop is added to a React component it will be treated as truthy, and if it is omitted completely it will be treated as falsey. Since the component is now remounted though, this `is_existing_offer` prop is unnecessary, the `id` route path param is what is still necessary as a dependency.

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    path="planner/:id"
    element={<PlannerWrapper key="planner_id" />}
  />
  <Route
    path="planner/"
    element={<PlannerWrapper key="planner_default" />}
  />
</Routes>
```

...

```
const PlannerWrapper = (props) => {
  // Get the offer's uuid from route to make API call and fetch the offer
  const { id } = useParams()

  ...

  // Fetch the associated offer via API and pre-populate components, runs when `id` updates
  // Only runs if `id` is truthy, i.e. defined
  useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/offer/${id}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
          console.log('Success:', result);
          setValues(result);
        })
    } else {
      setValues(initial_state);
    }
  }, [id]); // <-- id is referenced so it's a dependency

  ...
```

Note that even when using React keys on the routed component that it still needs to use the route path params as a proper dependency. This means that the React keys are also unnecessary since the `PlannerWrapper` effectively only triggers the `useEffect` callback and GET request if the `id` param is defined/truthy.

Answer (score 0):

Try nesting child routes:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="offers/" element={<DashboardOffers/>}/>
  <Route path="planner" element={<PlannerWrapper is_existing_offer={false}/>}>
    <Route path=":id" element={<PlannerWrapper is_existing_offer={true}/>}/>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Comment: Visiting `http://localhost:3000/dashboard/planner/1` returns `false` for `is_existing_offer` hmm

Comment: Not sure how the latest react-router works with `element`, but you can try to add a unique key to each route to force their re-render: `<Route key='planner' path="planner" element={<PlannerWrapper is_existing_offer={false}/>}>`

Comment: that didn't help either - thanks though!